# Гистограмма входящих символов

Tags: c

Здравствуйте. Мне очень нужен наводящий совет насчет проекта гистограммы входящих символов. Правильно ли понимаю, что можно вместо каждого входящего символа можно печатать знак |, что создаст своеобразные столбцы, которые будут изображать частоту вхождения символа в потоке, но это будут горизонтальные ряды, а как сделать вертикальные?

Comment: Видимо прочесть весь поток в память, определить высоту столбцов, рассчитать с какой строки (вывод-то будет "сверху-вниз") начинать вывод каждого столбца и напечатать (если ширины "экрана" для всех столбцов (символов) хватит).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так. Сейчас быстро за две минуты набрал. Может не сработать. Но вроде алгоритм правильный.

```
//overall обшее количество столбцов
//hist сколько раз данный символ встречается в тексте
for (int j=0;j<MAX(hist );j++) //макрос MAX ищет максимальный элемент в hist 
{
    for (int i=0;i<overall;i++) 
    {
        if (hist [i]> j) //< или > здесь управляет ориентацией гистограммы по вертикали
           puts("▲");  //Рисуем трифорс гистограмму
        else
        {
           puts(" ");
        }

    }
  puts("\n");
}
```